# Can we replace quotes with other charactors with c?

Tags: c, macros

I am making a bit annoying C header by replacing function names, numbers, etc to Korean, using the macro. like this

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#define 인트 int
#define 롱 long
#define 영 0
//and more and more
```

And I wanted to do the same to quote marks, but It didn't work.
my code was

```
#define some_korean "
```

when I compiled my program with this code, I got error C2001 
https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2001?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DKO-KR%26k%3Dk(C2001)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019
Is there any way to replace qoute marks in C using macros, or even without macros?

Comment: Maybe try the *stringization* operator: `#define KOREAN_STUFF(x) #x`

Comment: Please avoid linking to pages written in Korean(?).

Comment: Also try your hardest to write minimal, complete verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in C 2018 5.1.1.2 1, translation of C proceeds in 8 phases, simplified here:

1. Characters in the source file are mapped to a source character set in an implementation-defined manner.
2. Where backslashes mark continued lines, the lines are joined together.
3. The source file is grouped into preprocessing tokens and white space sequences.
4. Preprocessing directives are executed.
5. Characters in character constants and string literals are converted from the source character set to the execution character set.
6. Adjacent string literals are concatenated.
7. Preprocessing tokens are converted to tokens and analyzed syntactically and semantically.
8. External object and function references are resolved.

The problem you are encountering lies largely in phase 3. Macro replacement does not work on a text or character basis; it replaces preprocessing tokens, not characters. So you cannot replace “some_korean” with a quote mark. Even if the “some_korean” is recognized as a preprocessing token, a quote mark is not, and therefore it cannot be a preprocessing token in the macro replacement data.

Additionally, what strings you might mean by “some_korean” may be problematic. To serve as a macro name, it must be an *identifier* in the grammar. An identifier is an *identifier-nondigit* character followed by any number of either *identifier-nondigit* or *digit* characters (which are “0” to “9”). An *identifier-nondigit* is a *nondigit* (underscore, “a“ to “z”, or “A” to “Z”), a *universal-character-name* (further detailed in Annex D of the C standard), or any implementation-defined characters for this purpose.

Korean characters appear to be encompassed in the *universal-character-name* values listed in Annex D, so using them in identifiers should be fine, unless you are using some abnormal characters outside the listed values. However, your replacement text for each macro must consist of proper preprocessor tokens, which include whole strings and character constants but do not include individual quote characters.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The C preprocessor works on *tokens*, not on text. A token is a complete word like `int` or `some_variable`, or an operator or punctuation mark like `;` or `+=`, etc. A string literal `"hello world"` is a single token. Comments are eliminated before preprocessor replacement.

Something like `#define some_korean "` is a syntax error because the replacement text for the macro is not a sequence of tokens. That's even if `some_korean` is actually `some_korean` and not Korean characters. The problem is with the replacement text, not with the macro name. C doesn't work that way.

(In [K&R C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K&R_C), the preprocessor worked at a text level. So some K&R C compilers might be able to handle `"` as a macro replacement the way you want to do. But those compilers probably don't support Korean characters at all. K&R C was superseded in 1989 and almost completely vanished in the early 2000s.)

Answer (score -1):

A very few compilers allow Unicode chars to be used as the identifiers. As far as I know only the clang supports it without any problems.

https://godbolt.org/z/1SCv3c

So just stick to the ASCII.

Comment: The characters in the identifiers are not the cause of the message C2001. The cause is the isolated quote character. Non-ASCII characters in identifiers are explicitly permitted in standard C, per C 2018 6.4.2.1.